# „Incognito” in mandarin

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I.e. a person trying to hide his/her true identity? I asked Chinese friends but they are providing different options and I’m not sure if there is a direct equivalent of the English word. I’d like to have a traditional characters for this, thanks!

Comment: Google Translate: "Incognito" = 匿名 (anonymous)

Comment: How to translate it would depend on where/how you want to use it.

Comment: It is better to add the answers of your friends here.

Answer (score 2):

Browsing incognito is the phrase we often see on the internet . according to  this context, we use incognito to anonymously surf the internet and hence no trace is left

So we say 無痕上網。 痕in this Chinese phrase means trace . This Chinese phrase means surfing the website without trace

Answer (score 0):

**Oxford**

Incognito

> Adj.
>   化名的 huàmíng de
>   to be incognito
>   使用化名
>   to remain incognito
>   一直隐姓埋名
>
> Adverb
>   化名地 huàmíng de